# how can i change $scope property of controller from inside directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a button inside my view, which is handled entirely in the view, since its only a simple switch to toggle the view of an element with ng-show directive. I want to be able to toggle the view from inside the directive it self though.

Here an example code of what am trying to do:

```
<div>
<button ng-click="ToChange=true">
<my-directive ng-show="ToChange"></my-directive>
</div>

  .directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    ...
    controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.whenClickedThis = $scope.ToChange=false ???
    },
    ...
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your angular directive, you can have either access parent scope or isolate scope. If you are planning to use parent scope, then

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('mainController', function($scope){
    $scope.ToChange = false;
})
.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function($scope){
            //You can access $scope.ToChange here
        }),
        link : function($scope, $element, $attribute){
            //You can access $scope.ToChange here
        }
    }
});
```

```
<div ng-controller="mainController">
    <button ng-click="ToChange=true">
    <my-directive ng-show="ToChange"></my-directive>
</div>
```

If you are planning to create an isolate scope for your directive,

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('mainController', function($scope){
    $scope.ToChange = false;
})
.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope : {
            change : '='
        },
        controller: function($scope){
            //Now you can access $scope.change from here
        }),
        link : function($scope, $element, $attribute){
            //Now you can access $scope.change from here
        }
    }
});
```

```
<div ng-controller="mainController">
    <button ng-click="ToChange=true">
    <my-directive change="ToChange"></my-directive>
</div>
```

You can create a watch in your directive if you want to identify any changes to your variable

```
$scope.$watch('change', function(oldValue, newValue) {
    //Do something here;
});
```

Read more about angular scope [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module("test",[]);

app.directive("myDirective",function(){

    return {

        restrict: "EA",

        scope: true,

        link: function(scope,elem,attr){

            // code goes here ...
        }

    }   

 });
```

Comment: While code only answers may solve the problem, but it is always advisable to provide some explanation of the code

Comment: thanks for the advise, will consider it next time. What is if i have this in scope already?   scope: {
                ngLead: '=',
                ngShowLead: '=',
            },

Comment: This answer is lacking in explanation, I hardly see how one can understand how this solves the issue, especially someone new to directive, please elaborate

Comment: Also get rid of that `A` in the restrict, it looks like they want to restrict the directive to elements only.

Comment: Here it should be { scope: false } so that Directive uses its parent scope . If { scope: true } then Directive gets a new scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access parent scope variable in your directive.

```
angular.module('your-module').directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.ToChange = !$scope.ToChange;
    }
  };
});
```